# How to convince people not to buy, but adopt

Tags: dogs, adoption

I live in India where there are significant numbers of local dogs in need of adoption into loving homes. However many of the people looking to get a dog are instead more focused on purchasing Labradors, Golden retrievers and German shepherds.

Are there any strategies I can employ to encourage people to consider adopting a local dog instead?

Comment: What is the difference? Is it called "buying" if it's a popular breed and "adopting" if it's less popular? Or is it the age? Or where they come from?

Comment: @Fabian Buying is by giving money to breeders who force mothers to breed in puppy mills. Adopting is adopting stray dogs who live in the street.

Comment: Our dog used to belong to someone else and we ended up becoming his humans by accident. Not all adoptions are street dogs...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes sir but what I mean from the question is that the indian pariah breed is considered dirty and low status.

Comment: Hence marketing - our local street dogs had the same issues . Their snob appeal was improved by expatriates adopting them, and that used in marketing and said rebranding

Comment: "Buying" a dog does not always mean that it is coming from a "puppy mill", puppy mills are bad no argument there - but there is such a thing as a responsible breeder.

Comment: @motosubatsu millions of dogs, cats and other animals are euthanized in developed countries, while they die in accidents or killed in developing countries.  For every animal brought up by responsible breeders, one animal in the shelter loses its life.

Comment: @RamKeswani I understand that this is clearly a subject that you feel strongly about and I understand why, I despise "puppy mill"-type operations as well and I'm a big supporter of pet adoption (one of my own cats is adopted) but responsible breeders are a very different prospect and the notion that for every responsibly bred animal a sheltered one isn't adopted and thus loses it's life is overly simplistic and inaccurate. For my second cat I wanted a specific breed for it's traits and I wouldn't have adopted a substitute in it's place, it simply isn't the zero-sum game you think it is.

Comment: @motosubatsu they do get euthanized in shelters sir. And if they dont get killed, atleast they dont get that much love. Sir there are alot of type/breed cats in shelters. Cats are cats, no matter what breed. Sir differentiating breed is like religion, caste. Sir what trait did you want?

Comment: @RamKeswani I'm aware that animals will sometimes get euthanized in shelters - I've never said they didn't. My local cat shelter *never* puts a healthy cat down and all the animals there are very well treated, and yes *loved*. I was pointing out that it's not a one-for-one situation and that those (like me) who purchase an animal from a responsible breeder wouldn't necessarily just adopt a rescue instead and may not get the animal at all.

Comment: The breed (which is *nothing* like religion or caste) for my second cat was chosen because the temperament of that particular breed not only appealed to me but would also be the most likely to integrate well with my other, somewhat nervous cat who is adopted. And no, there weren't any of that breed in any shelters I checked which is not surprising as they are relatively rare cats.

Comment: @RamKeswani Except that's not what I'm saying at all and I'm sure (at least I *hope*) you realize that. You stated that anyone acquiring a pet faced the binary choice of adoption or "puppy mill", I'm merely pointing out that there is more to it than that. I have already stated that I am a big supporter of pet adoption and at no point have I suggested that a responsible breeder is better or "cooler" than adoption so please don't ascribe opinions to me that are clearly **not** what I have said.

Comment: @motosubatsu Sorry. But most breeders here in India are puppy mill types one. No one even knows about them, so no one asks for a 'reputable breeder' so there are ver less or maybe none.

Comment: I appreciate that the bad probably out number the good in India (and freely admit that I'm not there so the majority of my knowledge is internet-based) but I believe there is something of a fledgling drive from the KCI towards establishing better practices with things like their accredited breeder scheme. Maybe worth having a look into so if you get into a conversation with someone looking to buy rather than adopt and they are set on getting a specific breed you can at least point them in the direction of someone accredited?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Buying dogs is a "new" thing in India - most of my grandmother's dogs in the past have been street dogs. They've all been awesome in their own way.

In the modern context - Its all about networking, and marketing. In singapore, we have a handful of organisations - like [ASD](http://asdsingapore.com/wp/) and [SOSD](https://sosd.org.sg), who run programs to help "Singapore Specials" on the street, help do trap/neuter/release programs for humane population control (so fewer stray puppies), and generally create a framework for the things you need to get people to adopt dogs.

You noticed I used the term "Singapore Special" - its not a street dog. Its a *uniquely local canine* - and quite often *expatriates* adopted them. In singapore, there's other reasons, but its a selling point for more bougious folks. "Look, even the foreigners are adopting local dogs".

And of course, the power of social networking to get folks and dogs together. I believe SOSD runs training classes. They get people to foster dogs, and find homes for them were possible. They tell *stories* and use ..

Well - you advertise. And you don't play fair. Look at that widdle face.

[image: death by cute]

I think [that facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/SOSDSingapore/photos/a.219248514792432.84090.212281025489181/1712612132122722/?type=3&theater) speaks for itself. Its really a process - build awareness, build a brand, replace the prejudices people have with pride in *our* dogs, and people will be more likely to adopt.

You also make sure the animal's taken care of - and not turned out onto thr street(and there's no shame if it *really* dosen't work out and the dog's forever home is elsewhere) and that fostering, training and such is handled. In a sense - you need a certain degree of infrastructure in place.

By actually working to humanely reduce the population of strays - we're also solving a bigger problem.

Its also worth remembering many *purebred* and "designer" crossbreeds need rehoming too, as owners with the same mindset as yours get "tired" of their dogs. On the other hand, there's a dog run regular who tends to adopt senior breeds that are usually hard to adopt out. *Every* dog matters, but finding the right forever home isn't easy.

Comment: I disagree.I don't know about buying or adoption . But it has always been popular breeds getting adopted by people. Rarely anyone adopted the common street dog

Answer (score 4):

You have to get the word out (advertising or equivalent as in the previous answer).

I'd emphasize the advantages of adopting and disadvantages of buying (partially discussed by the previous post)

adopting advantages:

- gives homeless animals a home
- encourages healthier genetics of the species in question (because places selling often use breeders that have a tendency to inbreed for
  standards of looks)
- probably a friendlier and longer lived pet for the owner (inbred or partially inbred animals from breeders are probably less friendly and
  healthy than a normal genetic mix owing to genetic defects)
- reduces the population of stray animals
- more humane (breeders aren't always nice to their animals)
- saves the new owner money (adopting costs less)

Comment: There are animal organizations coming up. When I tell my friend (who will buy a dog soon) these things, they all just reply with stupid answers. When I say look at their conditions, they say they are adopted to it and its common for them to eat garbage. When I say thousand of them die in accidents everyday, they say adopting one wont make a change. It really hurts when the so called educated speak these. India needs alot of work.

Comment: All of the cats I've had (6) have been adopted.  I've been adopting pre-shelter (two of my cats were lost/abandoned; and four others came from owners who gave them up).  I've been very happy with the quality of them.  Breeders can give you a good looking animal, but you'll probably get a healthier and friendlier animal if it isn't from a breeder, and you'll be helping animals and the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Let me at the outset state that I strongly support adoption of strays, and I have adopted strays off the street myself.

The first thing to consider whether the Indian pariah breed (most strays in India) is appropriate for the typical pet-household. The breed has evolved naturally over hundreds/thousands of years and is very hardy and uniquely suited to the Indian climate. It is also loyal and protective.

However, it has also evolved to

- live in dog-packs (likely to go back to stray-life if given the chance)
- be more sociable with other dogs than with humans
- be highly territorial and  nervous outside its territory
- scavenge relentlessly
- be high energy (not suitable for the average pet owner)
- be strong-willed and have a mind of its own = recall is hard and it cannot be trusted off-leash.
- exploratory (hard to get it to walk with the human in a straight line because it constantly wants to sniff around).
- alert/responsive to other dogs barking and joining the chorus

All these behaviors are also present in other breeds, but to lesser extents. All of these undesirable behaviors can also be trained out of a dog, but it really requires an experienced handler. It also implies that this breed of dog is best suited to live on a "farm" kind of house with some area to own and guard - not the typical urban house.

People buy breeds based on 1) what they expect out of a breed and 2) what the breed has been bred (naturally or by human-selection) to do best.

Retrievers/labradors are uniquely suited to be average household pets. GSDs/dobermans not so much - they have specific needs, and are indeed less commonly owned than retrievers/labradors. Indian dogs are excellent for what they are, but the owner need to be suitable for their unique qualities.

For our country-house (large private acreage) in India we have the Indian pariah breed, and it is basically perfect. But in the city (still an independent house, not an apartment), I had tried it once (and again right now, with a pup), but it is/was not so great.